# The "OnCollisionEnter" function isn't being triggered in one case but is being triggered in another case

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I'm making a virtual reality application for the oculus platform with the unity engine & experiencing a problem in the process. For some reason, when i'm holding two objects (a hammer & a nail) with my controllers, between the two of them, the "OnCollisionEnter" function isn't being triggered, even though it's being triggered between any one of them & the target surface. Can someone please help me understand why it's happening? Is there a solution to it?

Comment: Is there a collider on both the objects and are they both set to isTrigger off?

Comment: @MarkManson yup

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that isTrigger is disabled.

[image]

Then add Rigidbody to both objects.

[image]

Also be sure to use `rigidbody` instead of `transform` to move and change position.

```
private Rigidbody rb;
private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
private void Update()
{
    rb.AddForce("some force vector");
    
    rb.MovePosition("some move vector");
}
```

Comment: I tried all possible solutions but couldn't resolve the issue. It seems to be some kind of hidden bug in the oculus SDK for unity. I've given up on solving this problem & found a workaround for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a recurring & unresolved issue related to how VR works with the unity engine.